# C# file download using WebBrowser

Tags: c#

Problem and solution is available at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/d338a2c8-96df-4cb0-b8be-c5fbdd7c9202/?prof=required

This work perfectly if there is direct URL including downloading file-name.

But sometime some URL generate file dynamically. So URL don't have file name but after requesting that URL some website create file dynamically and then open/save dialog comes.

for example some link generate pdf file on the fly.

How to handle such type of URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server code, then you could ensure that it adds the Content-Disposition header to the HTTP response, such as the following:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<put your filename here>
```

You could then look for that header on the client in order to decide to download the file in the background.

Even if you don't have control over the server code, check if the HTTP response already contains this header.  I believe that this is a standard header that most browsers look for in order to know how to download a file.

[This page](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) indicates some guidelines for using the Content-Disposition header, including the following items:

- The filename should be in US-ASCII
  charset.
- The filename should not have
  any directory path information
  specified.
- The filename should not be
  enclosed in double quotes even though
  most browsers will support it.
- Content-Type header should be before
  Content-Disposition.
- Content-Type
  header should refer to an unknown
  MIME type (at least until the older
  browsers go away).

Scott Hanselman also has [a small article on using this header](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheContentDispositionSagaControllingTheSuggestedFileNameInTheBrowsersSaveAsDialog.aspx).

Comment: I see now this is three years old, so possibly an older question & answer...

regardless, I was wondering how one could go about accomplishing, "You could then look for that header on the client in order to decide to download the file in the background."

I am not seeing any property of the WebBrowser that handles headers.